# Added webView in custom UITableViewCell. then rows are strucking

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am using custom tableview cell using auto layouts(constraints).In that tableview cell i added UIWebView, when i am scrolling the rows it will be strukking. pls help any one

```
 static NSString *cellidentifier=@"Cell";

subcell=(CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];


if (subcell==nil)
{
    subcell =(CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: please add some code & more description

Comment: What problem are you facing? Strukking means we don't understand.Please mention where you stuck?

Comment: When I am scrolling the rows,table view cells are jerking.... Slowly loaded

Answer (score 0):

it will struck because when you scroll the tableview the webview in the table view cell will also load the web request because of too many requests while scrolling it got struck. please check the meemory presure while scrolling

Comment: nope... just i am adding a webview to cell. but not return any url to webview

Comment: not working....                                                                                              static NSString *cellidentifier=@"Cell";
    
    subcell=(CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
   
    
    if (subcell==nil)
    {
        subcell =(CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CTEAuctionBidNowTVCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I give you some solution.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CustomTabelWebViewCell *cell = (CustomTabelWebViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomTabelWebViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
   if(cell==nil)
   {
     cell = nib[0];
   }
   //Here you load the webview
    .......
   return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 193;
}
```

Then getting height for tableViewCell-webview row call the below webView delegate method

```
 - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView 
 {
     CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
     frame.size.height = 1;
     aWebView.frame = frame;
     CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
     frame.size = fittingSize;
     aWebView.frame = frame;
     self.cellSize = fittingSize.height;
     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
     NSLog(@"Calling webViewDidFinishLoad. Cell size value: %lf", self.cellSize);
  }
```